# Avoiding NullPointerException from Boolean

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

I am trying to avoid a NullPointerException from a Boolean. I thought with the code below will work but it's not.

```
if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(shareConnection.getConnection())){ // This could be null, True or False

}
```

any ideas? I don't want to implement a `try catch` statement because this is already inside a catch.

**Edit**

```
public class ShareConnection{

    public boolean getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `shareConnection` initialized?

Comment: You are wrong. `if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(null)){
}` wont cause a NPE. Check here if you want : http://ideone.com/l2BbJu

Comment: Check shareConnection for NPE.

Comment: In your edit you used a primitive boolean, this can never be null. It has a default value of 'false'. You can just do if(shareConnection.getConnection()) {...} without comparing it to Boolean.TRUE. If you still have a NPE, it's probably caused somewhere else in the related code.

Comment: shareConnection = new ShareConnection(); that's how it is initialised @Iaalto

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(shareConnection.getConnection()))
```

The only way for NPE here is:

- `shareConnection` is `null`

Use a **Debugger** to analyze your program state.

Comment: You were right, shareConnection was throwing the exception. 
Thanks @Iaalto

Answer (score 1):

There are some readability issues here that also do much to make your life a lot harder.
1) Comparing two booleans (admittedly one wrapper and one primitive)

```
shareConnection.getConnection()
```

already returns a boolean.
There is no need to compare this boolean to Boolean.TRUE and use this in your if.
Simply use:

```
if(shareConnection.getConnection())
```

2) Name your methods

The method name

```
getConnection()
```

leads me to believe that when I call it, i get a (some sort of) connection.
Instead i get true or false.
This is as if i ask you for the hammer and you say "yeah".

3) The NullPointer Exception
As the previous answers already pointed out, the NPE is most likely caused by

```
shareConnection
```

Make sure that this is initialized before calling methods on this object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the primitive boolean instead of the Boolean class, that way it cannot be null.

Comment: equals shouldn't throw NPE, like user SURESH ATTA commented

Comment: Boolean.TRUE cant be null, it's a constant.

Comment: `Boolean booleanObject = null; boolean primBoolean = booleanObject; `, the second statement will throw NPE.